# How do I fix Ubuntu after using "sudo apt-get -remove pm-utils --purge"?

Tags: 11.10, login

My system is Ubuntu 11.10, Laptop Lenovo G570

I was having problems with hibernating so I looked up a couple of answers and tried a made the mistake of trying

```
sudo apt-get -remove pm-utils --purge"
sudo apt-get install pm-utils"
```

Then I restarted and at the login screen, I type my password and press enter, it flickers then crashes back to the login screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these at login terminal ( Ctrl+F1)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

also check the logs at `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`